# How to setup GIT for a GWT project

Tags: git, gwt, version-control

Which files and folders of a GWT project have to be tracked, which can I ignore?

I think ./src, ./test have to be tracked. I found out ./war is also important, but I've red, that it contains generated files.

I also found out that ./test-classes must be tracked, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you using maven project structure ? Have you build your project by some archetype ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually folders and files for git to version control GWT projects including:

```
.settings
 war
.classpath
.project
```

Usually files and folders ignored by git as (you can find [here)](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/GWT.gitignore):

> ```
> *.class
>
> # Package Files #
> *.jar
> *.war
>
> # gwt caches and compiled units #
> war/gwt_bree/
> gwt-unitCache/
>
> # boilerplate generated classes #
> .apt_generated/
>
> # more caches and things from deploy #
> war/WEB-INF/deploy/
> war/WEB-INF/classes/
>
> #compilation logs
> .gwt/
>
> #caching for already compiled files
> gwt-unitCache/
>
> #gwt junit compilation files
> www-test/
>
> #old GWT (1.5) created this dir
> .gwt-tmp/
> ```

In a word, files changes have impact for your project should be version controlled. And output files/folders or files have no impact for you project can be ignored by git.

Answer (score -1):

How to setup GIT for a GWT project:

I assume that you have a git repository created for your GWT project

1) **Clone your git repository** : Open git perspective in your IDE(eclipse) , paste your repository URL and follow the steps to setup a local git repo .

2) **Adding project to git** : Right click on the project in team click share project and select the repository you created .Done now all your local changes can be tracked by git .